# Django - How to represent the view count of any post in post app via highchart.js according to date

Tags: python, django, graph, charts, count

I have a basic django post app which displays post and its details when clicked , it also counts the view count.But actually i am unable to associate a time to when the post was actually viewed.

I want to represent data on highchart.js for each day that how many time a post was viewed.
The chart want to be horizontal and at each instance it shows recent 7 days data relative to each day.

total a screen representing a graph with 7 columns of how may time post was viewed each day.

If you can , pls include views.py and models.py for better understanding.

Most probably I am unable to make a data set that represents the vote count for each day in a list.

Comment: [This](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/04/03/how-to-integrate-highcharts-js-with-django.html) might be help you.

Comment: I had already gone through it , still im getting some errors while practicing

Comment: You should include what you have now and the errors you're running into.

Comment: See the updated part